# Resolving transitive dependencies from Artifactory in gradle

Tags: jenkins, gradle, artifactory, maven-publish

My project has two modules, `lib` and `lib-api`, with the following responsibilities

- **lib-api** - a pure java module that only contains interface files
- **lib** - an android library

and I'd like to jenkins publish both modules (as jars) to an internal artifactory server for other projects to be able consume.

Using the Jenkins Artifactory Plugin, I was able to publish jars for both modules to artifactory, but my other project that depends on `lib` fails to build with the following gradle error

> Could not find com.mygroup:lib-api:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT

### My setup

#### Build scripts

*lib-api/build.gradle*

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

group = 'com.mygroup'
version = project.version

publishing {
    publications {
        api(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
        }
    }
}
```

*lib/build.gradle*

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'

android { ... }

dependencies {
    compile project(':lib-api')
}

group = 'com.mygroup'
version = project.version
```

#### Jenkins Artifactory plugin config

- Gradle-Artifactory Integration

  - Publish artifacts to Artifactory

    - Publish Maven descriptors
  - Use Maven compatible patterns
- Invoke Gradle script

  - Use Gradle Wrapper
  - Tasks: `clean assemble -x preDexDebug -x preDexDAT -x preDexRelease`

#### Result in Artifactory repo

```
+-- libs-snapshot-local
|   +-- com
|   |   +-- mygroup
|   |   |   +-- lib
|   |   |   |   +-- 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
|   |   |   |   |   `-- lib-1.0.0-20150508-1.jar
|   |   |   |   |   `-- lib-1.0.0-20150508-1.pom
|   |   |   |   |   `-- maven-metadata.xml
|   |   |   |   `-- maven-metadata.xml
|   |   |   +-- lib-api
|   |   |   |   +-- 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
|   |   |   |   |   `-- lib-1.0.0-20150508-1.jar
```

### Question

My understanding is that artifactory/gradle should be smart enough to resolve `-SNAPSHOT` into the latest timestamped snapshot and that seems to be borne out by the fact that it manages to resolve `lib` whether I specify `latest.integration` or `1.0.0-SNAPSHOT`

How can I get gradle to resolve this transitive snapshot dependency from artifactory? Or get the artifactory plugin to publish the jar in such a way that gradle can resolve it?

**Working theory**

I noticed that the `lib-api` folder doesn't have a maven-metadata.xml file and the snapshot version folder doesn't have one either... or pom file. I suspect this might be the issue.

Artifactory's Jenkins plugin uses the gradle artifactory plugin under the hood for jobs that have Gradle-Artifactory integration enabled. According to the [gradle artifactory plugin docs](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Gradle+Artifactory+Plugin) the plugin ID changes depending on whether you are using the new (maven-publish) or old (maven) publishing mechanism.

Could this be the issue? Is the Artifactory plugin applying the wrong plugin ID, perhaps because it is making it's decision based on the android library module?

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr** Switching to the old maven plugin for gradle fixed it.

My `lib-api/build.gradle` now looks like this

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'

group = 'com.mygroup'
version = project.version
ext.artifactId = project.name.toLowerCase()
project.archivesBaseName = project.artifactId

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            pom.artifactId = project.artifactId
        }
    }
}
```

> *Note*: According to the gradle docs for the `maven` plugin, `pom.artifactId` must be explicitly defined if you've set archivesBaseName. That may have been the underlying issue with my previous configuration, but I did not go back and test it.